# jQuery datatable + Twitter bootstrap CSS issue

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, datatable

I am having a very strange problem with the styling of the table that has attached jquery datatable on it. Can someone help me with this one? I put the page here:

http://aldee07.eu5.org/test/

PS: for the link above, please just ignore the javascript error and malfunction of the scripts. I am just concern with the CSS of that page.

Thank you very much in advance. I am really stuck with this problem.

Comment: look at domain for all the css url's looks like something from your localhost. Very easy to look in browser console net/network tab and see all the aborted requests. You might see the css loaded since those url's will work on your localhost. But url provided has no css at all for anyone else

Comment: also path to all js is not correct

Comment: i'm sorry for that.. now, its all updated.. can you see it again please? thanks..

Comment: looks OK to me...please be more specific about issue

Comment: table width not set and is overflowing parent... is that what issue is? TD widths are set and add up to more than container

Comment: yes! that is the issue charlietfl . I could not find the reason why it happens.

Comment: can you edit the question and clarify what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem stems from bootstrap css sets `input` to default width of 260px which is too much for your table columns and is causing columns to be wider than script is telling them to be

This is not the 100% css cure but will show you the path to create a more robust css rule(s) to over ride the defaults.

After all the css link tags add the following:

```
<style type="text/css">
    input { width: 85%} 
</style>
```

Your table will shrink to fit parent and you just need to write some css improvements for the header `input` tags and perhaps `<TH>` padding . I would add a special class to row with the input elements and work from there.
Also bootsrap API has different classes for size of `input`

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/PSvyz/

Comment: excellent. it really solves the issue.. thank you very much charlietfl!

Comment: used browser console to inspect elements... the input's looked suspicious since they were only part that is non datatable standard. After that was easy to sort out. Doesn't take long and learning how to look at elements css is pretty easy